# Append multiple values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to make `arr = [5,4,3,2,1]` while still using both functions and without making `arr` global?  I need to pass multiple values back from `y()` to `x(`), but I don't want `arr` to = `[5,4,3,[2,1]]`.  Or do I need to redesign my functions?

```
arr = [5,4,3]

def x():
    arr.append(y())

def y():
    a = 2
    b = 1
    newArr = [a,b]
    return newArr

x()
print arr
```

Comment: Highly recommended read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong method:

```
def x():
    arr.extend(y())
```

`arr.append(thing)` means "add `thing` as a new item on the end of `arr`". `arr.extend(thing)` means "add all of `thing`'s contents to the end of `arr`".